# Android Studio Flamingo is missing Google Maps Activity template

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Earlier versions of Android Studio allowed the developer to create a project using the **Google Maps Activity** template as detailed on Google's [Maps SDK for Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start). However, Android Studio Flamingo does not list a Google Maps Activity template when creating a new phone and tablet project:

[image]

So what should a developer do instead to create a Google Maps Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 does not provide Google Maps Activity project from the start, however you may start New Google Maps Views Activity  after you created new project.

Steps are:

1. Start New Empty Project
2. Right Click on the package where you want to put you Activity
3. New -> Google -> Google Maps Views Activity

Do not forget to get your Google Map API key from https://console.cloud.google.com/ before running your project.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly pointed out, `Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1` lacks the ability to create a **Google Maps Activity**. The link you also provided has a [Look at the code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start?hl=ru#look_at_the_code) section which shows the `Activity` code, `Xml`, and a dependency that needs to be added to your module level `build.gradle`.

`Activity`:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

internal class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

`Xml`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Module level `build.gradle` (Ensure that `compileSdk` is set to **31 or higher** and `minSdk` is set to **19 or higher**):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    //...
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    // ...
}
```

Project-level `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    // ...
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}
```

Top-level `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// ...
```

`local.properties`:

```
MAPS_API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

Comment: Yeah, that is just a whole lot of configuration that a programmer has to slog through. I was hoping for something simpler, especially for new Android programmers. I'm really curious why Google removed the template.

Comment: The thing I've heard is that Google is looking to develop compose more actively for use in new projects. Since the Google Maps Activity template was made in xml, I would venture to suggest that perhaps we will see it in future releases of Android Studio and it will be built on the basis of compose

Answer (score 0):

> So what should a developer do instead to create a Google Maps Activity?

You could follow [the documentation that is not the quick start and shows you what to do without the template](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config).

Or [download an older version of studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#older-versions) if it's that important to you.