# Android Studio Flamingo android lifecycle issue with Android Devices, after adding Google Maps plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio-flamingo

Trying to build a cross platform connected device Google Maps enabled App using flutter framework on Android Studio Flaming 2022.2.1 Patch 2, without success. The flutter run works seemlessly until device dependency google_maps_flutter: ^2.4.0 is used under pubspec.yaml.
Also after added this

```
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.15
```

the problem still here.

iOS build is ok, also Android was perfect before Google Maps was added.

Please note that I have a strage issue, with my system PATH.
Doctor tell me that I have an Issue, but the PATH is perfect and built for iOS is ok.
I will write another post for this strange issue.

Coming back to this question, I searched for solutions over the web, but unsuccessfully, so this is my dev environment, hoping someone can help me.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # Google Area
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.4.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.15
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64, locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/maxmac/Development/flutter
    ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/MaxMac/Development/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/maxmac/Development/flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/maxmac/Development/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/MaxMac/Development/flutter/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/maxmac/Development/flutter. Consider
      adding /Users/maxmac/Development/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (3 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/maxmac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • iPhone 14 (mobile)           • 387BA0EA-FD06-4ABE-82E3-40FAE3AEBEDE • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)              • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.170

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

android/build.gradle.
As you can see I have added both
[ mavenCentral() ] and
[ maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } ]

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        //implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is [Adroid Project Structure settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH8F0.png)

The following error are generated (only for Android build)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.3.1/gradle-4.3.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.3.1/gradle-4.3.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Trying to do some additional setting, for example from here [maps template issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185879/android-studio-flamingo-is-missing-google-maps-activity-template), and again nothing.

Comment: I have had further tests, but again without finding a solution.
Changed on
<myapp>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

this line **distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
**, 
tha t was **distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3.1-bin.zip**, 
that can be changed also from Project Structure -> Gradle Version (not Plugin version).

Comment: Reference where I already try to find solutions
[Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#kts)

and here:
[github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60883)

Comment: Also deleting both .gradle directory, module and project level... and invalidating cache, nothing to do.

I'm quite sure that `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.15` is in origin corrupted, or something like this.

Comment: Your best bet would be to [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle%22) on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near to become really crazy, days trying to rebuild and change setup of my dev environment, and also after post the issue [on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/132046) without any answer, I have found the issue by myself.
This is definitely a bug on source code of the plugin `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15`.

I have found the bug on its source code, in its build.gradle.
You have to go here, for MAC OS:
`/Users/<your name>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15/android`

The guild.gradle, have this wrong dependence

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.1'
```

I have changed it in

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
```

... and after rebuilt, the problem is SOLVED.
I will try also with

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
```

Because the previous release, in the same pub.dev directory, `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.8`, has this dependence.

Now my `pubspec.yaml`, for Google Maps has got only this dependencies:

```
google_maps_flutter: ^2.4.0
```

Hoping this can help you.